# Custom Length Vibrations For Notifications in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, notifications, haptic-feedback

I am developing an app that sends vibrations to a users phone based on how long the user trying to reach them holds down a button. However, it has to work when the users app is not open. Is there a way to attach custom haptics to a notification to achieve this? I was also thinking that generating user feedback haptics locally when a message is received would work but I need it to work when the user is not using the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nice idea. I don't know if it's possible though

Answer (score 0):

This feature isn't available to the Firebase FCM library and would require the vibration settings configured on a per device basis.

Comment: I was thinking I could send a number (representing the length of the vibration) from user to user on firebase and then use that number to create a custom length local notification vibration on the receiving users phone. Would this be possible?

Comment: that isn't natively supported. you should look into how apps interact with the vibration settings directly and interpret FCM data as a service worker.